# Getting Error: no test specified when running a New Run in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

When I am running New Test Run in Heroku . I am getting error as Getting Error: no test specified when running a New Run in Heroku . I am sharing package.json for my build.I have also specified command in procfile. Request to please help in this Issue.

**Note**
Github repo is connected with Heroku & entire code is there.

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js",
    "start": "npm start"
  },
  "author": "****",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.25.4",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.11.2",
    "chromedriver": "^114.0.2",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "^4.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.25.4",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.25.4",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^7.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "properties-parser": "^0.6.0"
  }
}
```

[image: Issue Image]

I was expecting that my test must run sucessfully using procfile.

Comment: Looks like that's what you _want_ it do do. Your test script is `"echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reponse. But I have passed my test in procfile . Request to please suggest best ways for it

1 Using Procfile
2 Using test in package.json

If you observe the error, it is saying Error executing buildpack bin/test script i.e it is running node js through buildpack added via settings

Comment: Thank you @Chris . Your observation was correct. Appreciate it !!